# Is there a common solution to generate msoffice, libreoffice and pdf documents on the fly?

Tags: ruby, pdf, pdf-generation, ms-office, libreoffice

I would like to generate office documents (msoffice, oo) and pdf on the fly from *one source document*. Currently i think about opendocument as templates files and libreoffice-headless as converter.

Does anybody have experience on this topic and is there a (commercial?) ready to use solution?

Comment: Perhaps LaTeX or Postscript?

Comment: I do not have experience with LaTeX or Postscript. Is there easy software for DAU users to create template source documents?

Comment: what is DAU -- LaTeX is an old source document format that is **still** used for scientific papers.

Comment: There are any number of commercial solutions.  The trick - with DAU - is to choose a solution which has suitably easy authoring. That may dictate whether your source document is ODF or docx. You can use OO/LO to output the other (and PDF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A commercial solution is [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) which has a downloadable and cloud-service solutions using MSWord/OpenOffice documents as templates and providing template-population features, load balancing, doc/docx/odt/pdf/rtf/html production and quite a few other features.  One of it's key features is to generate point-in-time output in multiple formats (from the same template and data) as you mentioned.  It has at least one Ruby example to show the population features.  Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.

Another option is the open source JOD Reports.

I hope that helps.